# Cropping a wallpaper in order to have a crisp image

Tags: java, android, wallpaper, bitmapimage

I am currently working on a wallpaper application. Is there a way to make a bitmap look less blurry and more crisp once it is set as a wallpaper?
Does it just require cropping the picture and resizing it to fit the size of the screen perfectly, or there is some other way?

P.S. I read that the application wallpaper set and save is able to deliver very good quality wallpapers once launched!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you saving the bitmap? Try placing it in `/res/raw` as opposed to `/res/drawable` This prevents android from optimizing the image file, and should make it crisper.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! I just made the adjustment that you proposed and seems to be working pretty well . There is clearly a big improvement in the image's quality.